# pinch and zoom swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, pinchzoom

I am trying to implement a pinch and zoom on a picture passed into a controller which also contains a scroll view as per the tutorial here:

```
https://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/8/3/pinch-to-zoom-uiimageview-with-swift
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. My Code:

```
import UIKit
import Haneke

class imageZoomedController : UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var imageViewUrl : String?

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
        self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        if let url = NSURL(string: imageViewUrl!) {
            print("url is \(url)")
            self.imageView!.hnk_setImageFromURL(url)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
    {
        return self.imageView!
    }


}
```

I can see the image on screen but pinch and zoom gestures aren't taking effect

**Update**

Constraints for imageView:

```
Align center X to superView = 0
Align center Y to superView = 0
Trailing to superView = 0
Leading to superView = 0
Bottom space to superView = 0
Top space to superView = 0
```

Constraints for scrollView:

```
Trailing space to superView = -20
Leading space to superView = -20
Top space to topLayoutGuide = 20
Bottom space to bottomLayoutGuide = 20
//also tried 0 for all these as per demo but same outcome
```

Comment: Could you recheck if the scrollView has been set up correctly in storyboards? (i.e., no issue with autolayouts/constraints) ?

Comment: @mohonish My constraints are the same as those in the sample project. I will add them to the question as an update

Comment: @mohonish I solved it. I had't controll dragged the scrollView to the viewController to set it as the delegate! :)

Comment: hey thats great. That's a common mistake I've fallen for myself quite a few times. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used the same video.  The issue is you need to set your scrollView as a delegate.  Go to your IB and control drag the scrollView to the view controller and select Delegate.  This should fix it.